# Eucharistic miracles and Science

Tags: blood-of-christ, eucharistic-miracles

Are there any scientifically proven Eucharistic miracles? If there are, please provide sources / references (papers, articles, etc).

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  We are different to many other question and answer sites and I attach a link to our Tour to help you understand what we look for in questions that are likely to attract answers: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour